# How do I properly add custom CSS to a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adobe-brackets

I am writing an Extension for the Text-Editing software called Brackets, Brackets uses Bootstrap to style the Modal and CSS.
I am trying to add custom CSS to the Modal so that I can reformat, move and resize different elements on the Modal such as the Checkboxes and dropdown menus to make it look cleaner.

Everytime I attempt to add CSS to the Modal by either using  tags built in or a linked CSS the Modal doesn't load correctly.
The modal loads and then the whole screen gets a opaque black film over it, and the Modal becomes un-useable.

So I can deduct that I am not adding the CSS correctly as the Modal corrects the behavior when I remove the CSS I added.

How do I add custom CSS styling to this Bootstrap Modal?

```
<div id='templates_modal' class='template modal'>
<div class='modal-header'>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
    <h1 class='dialog-title'>{{TITLE_H1}}</h1>
</div>
<p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold;' id='templates_warning'>{{DOCTYPE_ALERT}}</p>
<p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold;' id='templates_warning'>{{CONTENT_ERROR}}</p>
<p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px;' id='templates_error'>{{NO_FILE_OPEN_ERROR}}</p>
<div class='modal-body'>
    <h4>{{LANGUAGE_SELECTION}}</h4>
    <p>{{LANGUAGE_DESCRIPTION}}</p>
    <select id='languages'>
        <option value=''>{{SELECT_LABEL}}</option>
        <option value='english'>en</option>
        <option value='german'>de</option>
        <option value='spanish'>es</option>
        <option value='french'>fr</option>
        <option value='italian'>it</option>
        <option value='chinese'>zh-cn</option>
    </select>
    <h4>{{CHARSET_SELECTION}}</h4>
    <p>{{CHARSET_DESCRIPTION}}</p>
    <select id="charset">
        <option value=''>{{SELECT_LABEL}}</option>
        <option value='utf8'>UTF-8</option>
        <option value='utf16'>UTF-16</option>
    </select>

    <h4>{{TITLE_H4}}</h4>
    <select id="doctype">
        <option value=''>{{SELECT_LABEL}}</option>
        <option value='html5'>HTML5</option>
        <option value='html4loose'>HTML4 Transitional</option>
        <option value='html4strict'>HTML4 Strict</option>
        <option value='xhtml1loose'>XHTML 1 Trasitional</option>
        <option value='xhtml1strict'>XHTML 1 Strict</option>
        <option value='xhtml11'>XHTML 1.1</option>
    </select>

    <h4>{{SECTION_TEMPLATES}}</h4>
    <p>{{SECTION_TEMPLATES_DESC}}</p>
    <ul class="checkbox-grid" id="libraries">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>' id="angularjs" value="angularjs" /><label for="angularjs"> Angular JS | 1.3.15</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>' id="angularmaterial" value="angularmaterial" /><label for="angularmaterial"> Angular Material | 0.10.0</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>' id="dojo" value="dojo" /><label for="dojo"> Dojo | 1.10.4</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"></script>' id="extcore" value="extcore" /><label for="extcore"> Ext Core | 3.1.0</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>' id="jquery111" value="jquery111" /><label for="jquery111"> jQuery | 1.11.3</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>' id="jquery214" value="jquery214" /><label for="jquery214"> jQuery | 2.1.4</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>' id="jquerymobile" value="jquerymobile" /><label for="jquerymobile"> jQuery Mobile | 1.4.5</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>' id="jqueryui" value="jqueryui" /><label for="jqueryui"> jQUery UI | 1.11.4</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>' id="mootools" value="mootools" /><label for="mootools"> MooTools | 1.5.1</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>'  id="prototype"value="prototype" /><label for="prototype"> Prototype | 1.7.2.0</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js"></script>' id="script_aculo_us" value="script_aculo_us" /><label for="script_aculo_us"> script.aculo.us | 1.9.0 (Requires Prototype)</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/spf/2.2.0/spf.js"></script>' id="spf" value="spf" /><label for="spf"> SPF | 2.2.0</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>' id="swfobject" value="swfobject" /><label for="swfobject"> SWFObject | 2.2</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r69/three.min.js"></script>' id="threejs" value="threejs" /><label for="threejs"> three.js | r69</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>' id="webfontloader" value="webfontloader" /><label for="webfontloader"> Web Font Loader | 1.5.18</label></li>
    </ul>
    <div class='modal-footer'>
        <a id='templates_modalGenBtn generate_html_btn' href='#' class='dialog-button btn btn-danger'>{{GENERATE_BUTTON}}</a>
        <a id='templates_modalBtn' href='#' class='dialog-button btn btn-danger' data-dismiss='modal'>{{CANCEL_BUTTON}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding custom classes (as your markup shows) *is* the correct way to do this. If your CSS is affecting how the modal renders, I suspect you're targeting the wrong portions of the modal's content. Can you trim this back to a minimal example, and add some of the CSS you've tried?

Comment: When I try to add a <link> from the HTML to the CSS page, the Opaque film appears.  So I am having difficulty manipulating the classes.  Unfortunately, the modal is built for a Brackets Extension.  So if I add the CSS you cannot see it 'fail' unless if you load the extension into Brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The modal loads, and then the whole screen gets a opaque black film over it, and the Modal becomes un-useable.*

You are missing 2 div `<div class="modal-dialog">` and `<div class='modal-content'>`

without `<div class="modal-dialog">` and `<div class='modal-content'>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkafuy2/1/)

and with

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#templates_modal">Open Modal</button>
<div id='templates_modal' class='template modal'>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
        </button>
         <h1 class='dialog-title'>{{TITLE_H1}}</h1>

    </div>
    <p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold;' id='templates_warning'>{{DOCTYPE_ALERT}}</p>
    <p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold;' id='templates_warning'>{{CONTENT_ERROR}}</p>
    <p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px;' id='templates_error'>{{NO_FILE_OPEN_ERROR}}</p>
    <div class='modal-body'>
         <h4>{{LANGUAGE_SELECTION}}</h4>

        <p>{{LANGUAGE_DESCRIPTION}}</p>
        <select id='languages'>
            <option value=''>{{SELECT_LABEL}}</option>
            <option value='english'>en</option>
            <option value='german'>de</option>
            <option value='spanish'>es</option>
            <option value='french'>fr</option>
            <option value='italian'>it</option>
            <option value='chinese'>zh-cn</option>
        </select>
         <h4>{{CHARSET_SELECTION}}</h4>

        <p>{{CHARSET_DESCRIPTION}}</p>
        <select id="charset">
            <option value=''>{{SELECT_LABEL}}</option>
            <option value='utf8'>UTF-8</option>
            <option value='utf16'>UTF-16</option>
        </select>
         <h4>{{TITLE_H4}}</h4>

        <select id="doctype">
            <option value=''>{{SELECT_LABEL}}</option>
            <option value='html5'>HTML5</option>
            <option value='html4loose'>HTML4 Transitional</option>
            <option value='html4strict'>HTML4 Strict</option>
            <option value='xhtml1loose'>XHTML 1 Trasitional</option>
            <option value='xhtml1strict'>XHTML 1 Strict</option>
            <option value='xhtml11'>XHTML 1.1</option>
        </select>
         <h4>{{SECTION_TEMPLATES}}</h4>

        <p>{{SECTION_TEMPLATES_DESC}}</p>
        <ul class="checkbox-grid" id="libraries">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>' id="angularjs" value="angularjs" />
                <label for="angularjs">Angular JS | 1.3.15</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>' id="angularmaterial" value="angularmaterial" />
                <label for="angularmaterial">Angular Material | 0.10.0</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>' id="dojo" value="dojo" />
                <label for="dojo">Dojo | 1.10.4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js"></script>' id="extcore" value="extcore" />
                <label for="extcore">Ext Core | 3.1.0</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>' id="jquery111" value="jquery111" />
                <label for="jquery111">jQuery | 1.11.3</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>' id="jquery214" value="jquery214" />
                <label for="jquery214">jQuery | 2.1.4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>' id="jquerymobile" value="jquerymobile" />
                <label for="jquerymobile">jQuery Mobile | 1.4.5</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>' id="jqueryui" value="jqueryui" />
                <label for="jqueryui">jQUery UI | 1.11.4</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>' id="mootools" value="mootools" />
                <label for="mootools">MooTools | 1.5.1</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>' id="prototype" value="prototype" />
                <label for="prototype">Prototype | 1.7.2.0</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js"></script>' id="script_aculo_us" value="script_aculo_us" />
                <label for="script_aculo_us">script.aculo.us | 1.9.0 (Requires Prototype)</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/spf/2.2.0/spf.js"></script>' id="spf" value="spf" />
                <label for="spf">SPF | 2.2.0</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>' id="swfobject" value="swfobject" />
                <label for="swfobject">SWFObject | 2.2</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r69/three.min.js"></script>' id="threejs" value="threejs" />
                <label for="threejs">three.js | r69</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="lib_checkboxes" data-script='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>' id="webfontloader" value="webfontloader" />
                <label for="webfontloader">Web Font Loader | 1.5.18</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class='modal-footer'> <a id='templates_modalGenBtn generate_html_btn' href='#' class='dialog-button btn btn-danger'>{{GENERATE_BUTTON}}</a>
 <a id='templates_modalBtn' href='#' class='dialog-button btn btn-danger' data-dismiss='modal'>{{CANCEL_BUTTON}}</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkafuy2/3/)

Use [bootstrap predefined classes](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp) to style and [grid system](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) to format the form inside modal

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkafuy2/5/)

And you can add custom css as like you are doing inline style `<p style='display: none; color: red; font-weight: bold;' id='templates_warning'>{{DOCTYPE_ALERT}}</p>` or put custom selectors and add those in style sheet, preferable is adding custom selector because later you can adjust modal content according to screen size with [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

e.g

```
<p class="nodisplay" id='templates_warning'>{{DOCTYPE_ALERT}}</p>
```

and in style sheet

```
.nodisplay {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hkafuy2/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  How do I link the CSS stylesheet to the HTML page?  When I tried to add a <link> in the top of the HTML page the page showed that opaque black film over it.

Comment: you already have bootstrap.css in HTML head section, if you want to add another sytlesheet simply put it under bootstrap.css like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstylesheet" />` and please  put `<div class='modal-content'>` in modal otherwise you will keep getting the `opaque black film` it's basically the modal overlay which you are getting when open the modal so put this missing div `<div class='modal-content'>` in modal see the modal code above in answer where i put it

Comment: see updated answer, just noticed that there is another div missing `<div class="modal-dialog">` in modal

Comment: Thank you again for your answer.  Forgive my noobness, but you said I already have bootstrap.css in the HTML head section... I can't find where I have that. So I don't know where I can add another Stylesheet to it.  Can you please direct me to where I can add the other Stylesheet?

Comment: in question you mentioned that `Brackets uses Bootstrap to style the Modal and CSS. ` how you know it is using `Brackets uses Bootstrap to style the Modal and CSS. ` when you don't know where is bootstrap css but still you really don't know then go with the inline style like you already trying, coz there is not must custom style in modal which makes any difference if you do it inline or with custom selectors.

Comment: thank you.  So you are suggesting I add 'inline-css' to the modal to resize/reformat my checkboxes?  ||| PS: Thank you for the catches on the HTML <div class="modal-dialog">

Comment: I think you need this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp , style the form with predefined bootstrap classes, e.g `<select id="doctype">` give it a class `<select id="doctype" class="form-control">` and put it inside `<div class="form-group"></div>` and also you can use `<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12></div></div>"` to format the form http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp and then what left to customize, use inline-styles

Comment: Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/4hkafuy2/5/ gives you complete idea and you can continue with it for rest of the elements in modal

Comment: I just had a Ah ha moment.  Thank you VERY much for writing that example.  I get it now.  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

in html file add ids like :

```
 <div class="modal fade"  style="border-radius : 20px !important;" id="createPageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"  style="border-radius : 20px !important;" role="document">
                       <!--here--> <div class="modal-content" id="page_modal_content">
                       <!--here--><div class="modal-header" id="page_modal_header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Please enter your credentials to login.</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"> 
                                <form class="login_form ">
                                    <label for="user_form_name">User name</label>
                                    <input id="user_form_name" type="text" placeholder="User name" required />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button style="border-radius : 20px; width : 45%;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <button style="border-radius : 20px; width : 45%;" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And css should be :

```
#page_modal_content {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
} 
#page_modal_header {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important;/* you must add important*/
  border-top-left-radius: 10px !important;
}
```